# Method to solve probability of chips

Tags: combinatorics

A bag contains six chips, numbered 1 through 6. If two chips are chosen at random without replacement and the values on those two chips are multiplied, what is the probability that this product will be greater than 20?

I tried to solve by counting the total possibilities (36) and solving for 6 choices that worked, e.g. $4x6, 5x5, 5x6, 6x4,6x5,6x6$... so I thought the probability would be $1/6$.

How is my method incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample space size isn't 36.  How many choices for the first chip; how many for the second (without replacement)?

Comment: 6 choice for first and 5 choices for second.

Comment: Correct. That should help you wrap up the problem!

Comment: Also note @Ben that you have to modify your list of outcomes.  Two of them can't happen.

Comment: @John: Nice catch!

Comment: so the answer is 2/11? my book says 2/15. is the book misprinted?

Comment: @drhab  if the first chip has $6$ choices and the second chip has $5$ choices then we have a total of $11$ choices. given that the chips are not replaced two possibilities, $5x6$ and $4x6$ are possible, so I think $2/11$. Am I correct?

Comment: Hi Ben,  If you have 6 choices for the first draw and 5 for the second draw, you have a total of $6\cdot 5=30$ choices for the two draws.  It might be a good exercise for you to write out these 30 possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

The order is not relevant here (e.g. first a $6$ and then a $3$ comes to the same as first a $3$ and then a $6$).

Taking that into account there are $\binom{6}{2}=15$ possibilities in total, and in $2$ of them the product will exceed $20$.

You can also solve it by neglecting that the order is not relevant. Then you come to $6\times 5=30$ possibilities and in $4$ of them the product will exceed $20$.